# Fitting a mixture of lognormal distributions in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

[scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) provides a nice way to fit a single lognormal distribution. I see that [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html) has the ability to fit normal (Gaussian) mixtures. Is there a straightforward way to fit a mixture of two lognormal distributions? If not, is there a superior approach to optimizing the parameters "by hand" either directly with scipy.optimize or by defining the mixture distribution as a subclass of [scipy.stats.rv_continuous](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html)?

Comment: You could `log`-transform your data and fit a `GMM` to it, something in the lines of `X = np.log(X)`, but... I believe there is no an *easy* way to exactly fit a lognormal distribution with `scikit-learn`, however, you can always have a look at the [`GMM` code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c957249/sklearn/mixture/gmm.py#L115) and extend it yourself. You could even send the implementation back to `scikit-learn`!

Comment: `scipy` gives the flexibility to fit the location for the lognormal distribution which would be lost with the `log` transformation -- and it felt problematic to make that choice upfront but maybe it isn't in practice. If it turns out the location parameter really is necessary, extending `GMM` might be the nicest approach. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Yep, that is the main problem with the log transformation of the data. You are not fitting a lognormal mixture, you are fitting a gaussian mixture to the log-transformed data. It is not the same, but depending on which is your application, it might still work. Good luck with extending `GMM` if that is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this and it worked great for me:

https://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GeneralMixtureModel.html

example usage:

```
from pomegranate import *

x = np.array(df['foo']).reshape(-1, 1)

model = GeneralMixtureModel.from_samples(LogNormalDistribution, n_components=2, X=x)
model.fit(x)
pomegranate_clusters = model.predict(x)
```